# VB - sql query to reader or datatable then to text boxes

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable, datareader

i have created a SQL query that returns a table:

FAMILY | ISSUES
family a      |  11 
family b      |   5
family c      |  17
family d      |  28

i have, in Visual Basic (visual studio 2015) returned this data to a datatable using this code:

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("connection string here")

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
Dim da2 As New SqlDataAdapter
cmd.CommandText = "select ........ "
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = conn

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()`
```

***here is where i am lost ***

i need code to select the number of Issues ( column 2 ) based on the value in column 1 (family)

my issue is that some times, one of the families may not HAVE a record, so the dataset could have only families a, c, and d...the next time it could have families b, and d.  so i cannot really use row(#). i need code that i can reference the family name and then return the number of issues, put that number into a string, and then place that value in a text box.

i'm good with assigning the string to a variable and then into the text box...its the in-between that i can't figure out!

Thank you!

Comment: If you fill a datatable rather than trying to anticipate what will be returned, you'll get N rows.  `"select....." doesnt tell us much about what the data looks like.  If there is a where clause you can control what comes back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`, then use Linq-To-DataTable to get what you need. Also, always use the `using`-statement:

```
Dim table = New DataTable()
Using conn As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
    Using da = New SqlDataAdapter("select ........ ", conn)
        da.Fill(table)
    End Using
End Using

Dim matchingFamily = From row In table.AsEnumerable()
                     Where row.Field(Of String)("Family") = "family a"
If matchingFamily.Any() Then
    Dim familyIssueCount As Int32 = matchingFamily.First().Field(Of Int32)("Issues")
    ' ... '
End If
```

If it's possible that multiple rows contain this family you might use a different approach since `First` will pick an arbitrary row. One way is using a `For Each` to enumerate them or use `matchingFamily.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("Issues"))` to sum the issues.

If you don't need all records in memory you could also select only the relevant records from the database with `...WHERE Family = @family`.

Comment: Thank you for this information - i will work with this and see if i can find a solution that works....i think i have something in mind but will play around with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub GetFamilyIssues(ByVal FamilyName As String)
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
    cn.Open()

    Dim sql As String = "select * from FamilyIssues where FAMILY = @Family"

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Family", FamilyName)

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    txtIssues.Text = ""
    If reader.HasRows Then
        txtIssues.Text = reader("ISSUES").ToString()
    End If

    cn.Close()
End Sub
```